# Application in smart watches

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to make a application in smart watches including apple watches as well can I make this using Flutter and if I can make those things in flutter. Is there any documentation which can help me in the making of that

I tried to look at the docs but not able to find good solution.

Comment: Flutter doesn't support watchOS for app development. Packages are available to communicate between a flutter app and a watchOS app, but the watchOS app needs to be written in Swift

Comment: What could be the best package for the watchOS and wear OS which cover both

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You just have to search at pub.dev, but this is one https://pub.dev/packages/watch_connectivity